# Line chart - insert dynamic lines which show boundary values, different for certain dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Line Chart with daily values of the amount of vitamins added to a product.
I want to add 3 new lines which shows the Maximum vitamins allowed, minimum allowed and the Goal amount.
The desired values are changing over time.
The desired value is in a table with the start date from when It starts to be applied.

[image]

This is the table whith so far 2 dates.
When I put this table into the line chart, it shows just a point, not a line.
I guess because there are only two dates, and not dates for every date inbetween and until today.

Is it possible to make a line out of this data? Possibly without creating new rows for every day.

[image]

I am a beginner in powerbi.